# Error "mkdir() no such file or directory" Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, vue.js, mkdir

Tengo un proyecto en github... en mi pc donde esta el repositorio maestro.

Funciona correctamente pero tengo otra pc donde esta clonado el proyecto desde github tengo este error `mkdir() no such file or directory`.

Comento un poco sobre el proyecto, esta desarrollado en **laravel** **vuejs** y en el modulo donde cargo un archivo excel hago que antes me cree una carpeta con `mkdir()` donde guardar el excel.

En las dos pc tengo las mismas versiones de php, en incluso ya realice "composer update" y composer "install", por su puesto antes de iniciar el proyecto "mpn install".

Un poco de mi script:

```
 // return $decode;
    $filename = 'productos.' . $extension;
    $carpeta = "F:/xampp/htdocs/carpeta/public/app/excel/empresa/db/" . $dir;
    //dd($carpeta);
    if (!file_exists($carpeta)) {
      mkdir($carpeta, 0777, true);
    }
    $pathFile = 'http://localhost/carpeta/public/app/excel/empresa/db/' . $dir . '/' . $filename;
    $path = public_path() . '/app/excel/empresa/db/' . $dir . '/' . $filename;
    file_put_contents($path, $decode);
```

Answer (score 1):

Al ser el mismo código, y funcionar en un sistema si y en otro no, debe ser una diferencia en el entorno.

La única y más probable explicación que encuentro es que en un PC exista la **unidad F:** y en el otro no.